# Visual Studio 2012 & IIS 7.5 running very slow on localhost

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, iis, visual-studio-2012, iis-7.5, webmatrix

I am working on a project, the team (and vs2012) by default uses iis7.5 during development.
Very recently (yesterday) the sites I was debugging start loading very slow.
Using fiddler I could see that it would take about 30 seconds for every single call that is being made.
so "localhost:{port}" takes 30 seconds (2kb), once that finally comes back and the page starts to load it calls all the css and js files, each take about 30 seconds to load.
As this is a large application it quickly became unusable.
this happens whether I am debugging, or loading a page without debugging.
This same behavior happens an all sites on my dev machine, even plain newly build site exhibits the same behavior  And occurs in all browsers.

I am able to "resolve" the problem several ways.

```
1. Switch from iis 7.5 to visual studio dev server. 
(url does not change localhost:{port} to localhost:{port}.)

2. In web matrix, if I change the url from localhost:{port} to 
http://{machinename}:{port} the site then runs faster (normal speed), 
but debugging becomes and issue.
```

option 1 above does the trick and I dont seem to be effected too much by the change.

I am very curious as to why this is all of a sudden happening though, and would really like to fix the problem.

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What changed?... any recent updates installed or changes made to cause this sudden slowness?

Comment: I did install VS2012 update 3 around the same time, I dont know if I can roll this back though

Comment: Try uninstalling the update via Windows Updates